# How to set the arraylist to object after the postExecute of asyncTask?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have 2 asyncTasks. One for GetCheckLists another for GetCheckListItems. 
In CheckList class, it has checkListId,Title,etc and arrayList of checkListItems.

First I get all the checkLists using GetCheckListAsyncTask. Now for each checkList I am calling GetCheckListItemsAsync task to get all the checkListItems.

Now onPostExecute method of GetCheckListItemsAsyncTask I want to set the checkListItemArrayList.

How can I make sure to add checkListItemArrayList to checkList item's object?

CheckListActivity:

```
    public class CheckListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckListAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<CheckList> checkLists = new ArrayList<>();
    private CheckList mCheckList;
    private ArrayList<CheckListItem> itemList;
    private ArrayList<CheckList> checkListArrayList;
    private CheckListAdapter mAdapter;
    JSONArray checkListsItemArray,checkListArray;
    public int iterationCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);

        checkListArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        mEventId = mIntent.getStringExtra("eventId");

        mCheckList = new CheckList();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckListActivity.this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new CheckListAdapter(checkListArrayList,CheckListActivity.this,CheckListActivity.this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        GetCheckListAsyncTask getCheckListAsyncTask = new GetCheckListAsyncTask();
        getCheckListAsyncTask.execute(mEventId);

    }

    }

    @Override

    public class GetCheckListsItemAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        private String api;
        private JSONObject jsonParams;
        public GetCheckListsItemAsyncTask(){}

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                api = getResources().getString(R.string.server_url) + "api/checklist_items/getChecklistItems.php";

                jsonParams = new JSONObject();
                String checklistId = params[0];  // params[0] is username
                jsonParams.put("checklistId", checklistId);

                ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest(api, jsonParams);
                return request.sendRequest();
            } catch(JSONException je) {
                return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
            }
        }  //end of doInBackground

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            Log.e("ServerResponse", response.toString());
            try {
                int result = response.getInt("result");
                String message = response.getString("message");
                if (result == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //code after getting profile details goes here
                    checkListsItemArray = response.getJSONArray("checklistItems");

                    for (int i = 0; i < checkListsItemArray.length(); i++) {

                        int pendingTasks = 0,completedTasks = 0;

                        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

                        CheckListItem checkListItem = new CheckListItem();

                        JSONObject subObject = checkListsItemArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String checkListItemName = subObject.getString("text");//name of the attribute in response
                        String checkListItemBudget = subObject.getString("budget");//name of the attribute in response
                        String checkListItemTimedate = subObject.getString("time_due");
                        String checkListItemReminder = subObject.getString("reminder");
                        String checkListItemId = subObject.getString("checklistItemId");
                        String checkListItemStatus = subObject.getString("status");

                        if (checkListItemStatus.equals("1")) {
                            completedTasks++;
                        }
                        if (checkListItemStatus.equals("0")) {
                            pendingTasks++;
                        }

                        checkListItem.setTitle(checkListItemName);
                        checkListItem.setBudget(checkListItemBudget);
                        checkListItem.setDateTime(checkListItemTimedate);
                        checkListItem.setReminder(checkListItemReminder);
                        checkListItem.setCheckListItemId(checkListItemId);
                        checkListItem.setStatus(checkListItemStatus);
                        checkListItem.setPendingItem(pendingTasks);
                        checkListItem.setCompletedItem(completedTasks);

                        itemList.add(checkListItem);//adding string to arraylist
                    }

                    if(checkListArrayList.size() < iterationCount) {
                        iterationCount++;
                        String checkListId =
                                checkListArrayList.get(iterationCount).getCheckListId();
                        CheckList checkList1 = checkListArrayList.get(iterationCount);
                        checkList1.setCheckListItemArrayList(itemList);

                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //code after failed getting profile details goes here
                }
            } catch(JSONException je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, je.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } //end of onPostExecute
    }



    public class GetCheckListAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        private String api;
        private JSONObject jsonParams;
        public GetCheckListAsyncTask(){}

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                api = getResources().getString(R.string.server_url) + "api/checklist/getChecklists.php";

                jsonParams = new JSONObject();
                String eventId = params[0];  // params[0] is username
                jsonParams.put("eventId", eventId);

                ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest(api, jsonParams);
                return request.sendRequest();
            } catch(JSONException je) {
                return Excpetion2JSON.getJSON(je);
            }
        }  //end of doInBackground

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            //Log.e("ServerResponse", response.toString());
            try {
                int result = response.getInt("result");
                String message = response.getString("message");
                if (result == 1 ) {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //code after getting profile details goes here

                    checkListArray = response.getJSONArray("checklists");

                    for (int i = 0; i < checkListArray.length(); i++) {
                        CheckList checkList = new CheckList();
                        JSONObject subObject = checkListArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String checkListName = subObject.getString("checklist");//name of the attribute in response
                        String checkListBudget = subObject.getString("budget");//name of the attribute in response
                        String checkListIcon = subObject.getString("icon");
                        String checkListId = subObject.getString("checklistId");

                        checkList.setCheckListTitle(checkListName);
                        checkList.setBudget(checkListBudget);
                        checkList.setImageIcon(checkListIcon);
                        checkList.setCheckListId(checkListId);

                        checkListArrayList.add(checkList);

                        iterationCount++;
                        new GetCheckListsItemAsyncTask().execute(checkListId);

                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    if ((progressDialog != null) && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //code after failed getting profile details goes here
                    if ((progressDialog != null) && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            } catch(JSONException je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(CheckListActivity.this, je.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } //end of onPostExecute
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

    }
}
```

How to set CheckListItemsArrayList to the objects of checkListArrayList sequence wise? Please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question. It is very confusing.

But I think that you want to add items to your AsyncTask class.

You can use the **Constructor Method** for this.

> ```
> GetCheckListAsyncTask getCheckListAsyncTask = new GetCheckListAsyncTask(checkListsItemArray);
>         getCheckListAsyncTask.execute(mEventId);
> ```

And for ***AsyncTask*** Just Add:

> ```
> JSONArray m_checkListsItemArray;
>
> public GetCheckListsItemAsyncTask(JSONArray checkListsItemArray){
>        m_checkListsItemArray = checkListsItemArray; 
>        //Do something here with checkListsItemArray;
> }
> ```

*And use m_checkListsItemArray anywhere in the AsycTask class.*

Comment: no I want to set the checkListItemArrays to the checkListArrayList's objects.@Saini

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a little bit confused about your concept.

Comment: Can you explain me in a simple way?

Comment: Variable names you used here such as checkListItemArrays, checkListArrayList's are a little bit confusing..Just tell me in simple words what do you want the program to do.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you start a task, you have no control when it ends.  The tasks are running Asynchronously so they won't end in the order you start them.  Maybe have a field level Array or ArrayList that adds results each time a task ends and then when everyhthing has ended you can work with the array results.

Comment: could you please explain through code? That's somwhat I tried to do. Created on iteration count variable and increamented it in GeckCheckListAsyncTask 's postExecute method. and tried to access it in GetCheckListItemsAsyncTask and set the arraylist in the object of checkList. But it's throwing index out of bound exception.@usajnf

Comment: Which line generates the index out of bounds exception?